# element.attributes in IE8 has too many items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I ran across a website that shows inconsistent behavior with `element.attributes` in IE8.
The website is [www.leumi.co.il](http://www.leumi.co.il)

In any "regular" modern browser, the following code returns just a few attributes, usually in correlation with the actual attribues that were defined in the HTML.

```
jQuery('li')[0].attributes.length;
jQuery.each(jQuery('li')[0].attributes,function(i,a){console.log(a.name)});
```

But in IE8, the same code in the same page returns over 100 attributes. I'm only guessing here, but it seems to be the list of "calculated style" of the element.

I checked this on other pages in IE8 and it doesn't happen - meaning `element.attributes` usually returns the attributes defined in the original HTML, even in IE8.

So my question is - why is this happening in this particular website in IE8?
And are there other cases where this might happen? (other browsers?)

Comment: An used library adds the attributes to create a kind of a polyfill for missing `getComputedStyle()` in IE8?

Comment: probably not, because I used SingleFile (chrome plugin) to save the page's HTML from chrome, without any javascript, then I opened this file in IE8 and I'm seeing the same thing

Comment: A "SingleFIle"? There's a bunch of linked JS files in the page you've linked to in the question.

Comment: SingleFile is a plugin for google chrome that can take a page with all it's resources and save it as one single HTML file. I used it to save the website in the question, from google chrome, but excluded javascript files. So the result is a static HTML page. then I opened this file in IE8 and ran the test code in the question (after adding jQuery manually). And I get the same results. So this can't be a Javascript Library that does this only in IE8. Maybe some CSS trick?

Comment: Not familiar with the said plug-in, but are the attributes there if you'll view the source code? Maybe it's the plug-in adding the attributes?

Comment: @Malki, so that plugin takes a snapshot of the DOM, right? Then the extra attributes are already part of your single, no-script file.

Comment: No, the plugin did not add these attributes. I checked the HTML, and also ran this test on the same file in chrome, firefox, and IE11 and the results are as expected. Only IE8 shows the strange behavior.

Comment: @Malki Please re-read my first comment. There has to be a script creating the attributes. Many libraries creates polyfills for older IEs only, but there's no reason to polyfill something existing in other browsers, hence this happens in IE8 only. Just reduce libraries and scripts on the page until the extra attributes vanishes. If they won't, most likely it's the plug-in adding the attributes.

Comment: @Malki, another possible explanation is that *your browser* is running an extension that adds the attributes. In that case, the problem would be strictly local. Maybe try with another IE8?

Comment: @Teemu I understand that. But how can this happen when I save the HTML from chrom without any javascript, and then open this file in IE8. I also just now tries removing all of the CSS from that file, and this still happens.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi While this is a possibility, wouldn't the same thing happen in other pages? I'm seeing this only on this page and only in IE8. other pages in IE8 don't have this problem. Also, I'm running this on a clean VM. I didn't install any extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested - I found the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

This caused IE8 to load the document in "Quirks Mode" and this is what caused the problem.